# Replace old shower drain from the 80’s

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, remodeling

newbie there

I move into a house from the 80’s. The bathroom needed to be renovated.
I have demolished the shower pan and now need to replaced the shower drain attached. It seems like a valve on top attached to the frange by 4 very corroded hex screws. The drain is directly in the concrete slab. Not sure if there is a PVC pipe under…
Is it possible to be replaced? How do I get from there, should I open the concrete a little bit around and cut the pipe or is there another way? I heard about the Flo fx shower drain that could work if it is cast iron pipes. Has anyone tried it?
Thanks [image]

Comment: why does it look like toilet drain ?

Comment: Way too small for a toilet drain. In a house built in the 80's it's not likely to be cast iron, but it could be if it was a high-end, expensive house when built. There will definitely be some sort of pipe beyond this opening - your shower drain water does not just run through an empty space in the concrete, there will be a pipe lining that of some sort.